# Adding DevExtreme Grid to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, devextreme

I am trying to figure out how to add DevExtreme's grid to wordpress.

Here is an example of what I am trying to add to wordpress.

http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/datagridgridpagingandscrollingpager/generic/light/default

I have added the scripts in the functions.php file with wp_enqueue_script, so that this will load with all the pages.

Now I am trying to figure out how to add the data part

I am now trying to figure out where I can add the code, markup and data. Each of these pieces will be different on each load.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I can put this?

Thank you so much!

```
<div id="gridContainer"></div>


$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
dataSource: customers,
paging: {
    pageSize: 10
},
pager: {
    showPageSizeSelector: true,
    allowedPageSizes: [5, 10, 20]
},
columns: ['CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax']
});
```

and

```
var customers = [{
"ID": 1,
"CompanyName": "Super Mart of the West",
"Address": "702 SW 8th Street",
"City": "Bentonville",
"State": "Arkansas",
"Zipcode": 72716,
"Phone": "(800) 555-2797",
"Fax": "(800) 555-2171",
"Website": ""
}, {
"ID": 2,
"CompanyName": "Electronics Depot",
"Address": "2455 Paces Ferry Road NW",
"City": "Atlanta",
"State": "Georgia",
"Zipcode": 30339,
"Phone": "(800) 595-3232",
"Fax": "(800) 595-3231",
"Website": ""
}]
```

Comment: Basically you want to add some custom JavaScript to a post. Check if [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#JavaScript_in_Posts) helps. If not, try to ask at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. That is the way I was going, but it just looked really messy and I thought there should have been a better way. Also with any line breaks in the <script> tags it causes issues. I know there are ways to get around that, but it just seems like a hack

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you may need a custom post type or custom fields that allow you to enter and manage fields like: "CompanyName" "Address" "City" "State" "Zipcode" "Phone" "Fax" "Website"

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Unless those fields are associated with a post, I don't know how you can manage them, grid or otherwise!

Comment: thanks for the comment! The fields are mapped to the var customers. So I am pretty sure it does not need the custom fields in this case